# Was Secondary NameNode Present in The FIRST GENERATION HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Can you please clarify if there was the concept of Secondary NameNode present in the first generation hadoop? Or was it introduced in the Second Generation HDFS?

And What is the concept of Active and Passive Nodes in HDFS?

Comment: Can you clarify, by first generation do you mean versions prior to 'YARN'/0.23 branched versions?

Comment: Perhaps the second question should be separate and have more details. I answered your first question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title question, the secondary namenode was added by HADOOP-227 (see [the JIRA for more details](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-227)), and committed to Hadoop version 0.11 in 2006, so its been in HDFS for a long time.